# jquery mobile multipage app, chrome navigates multiple times to domain

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I have jquery-mobile multipage app (pure client-side)

Works well on FF, but chrome navigates multiple times to domain

I included alerts (indicating event and hash of URL) in two events:
- `$( document ).one("pageshow", '.page',function() {`
- `$( window ).on("navigate", function() {`

pageshow has .one attachment, but it is still triggered multiple times.

Comment: try using the core jquery not mobile

Answer (score 0):

That was caused by src="#" attributes of iframes inside popup divs. I changed src="#" to src="". (I change src of iframe when popup is poping-up to prevent unnesesery loads of map.html)